# Where is נהר פקוד?

Tags: talmud-gemara, geography, maseches-zevachim

Is this a actually river named pikod? Are there records where it is?

(Mentioned in Zevachim 8b [among other places.](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%A8%20%D7%A4%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93&filters=Talmud&var=1&sort=r&lang=bi))

Comment: According to the footnotes in the Soncino Talmud (San. 32b, footnote 30), Nehar Pekod is west of Nehardea.

Comment: https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/nehar-pekod

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is found in [this article](http://benyehuda.org/friedberg/hasugar.html)

> כאשר כבדה ידו על עמנו, יצא ר' חנניה, בן אחי ר' יהושע הלוי, לשבת לבטח
>   בין אחינו שבבבל, ובראותו עני היושבים בארץ הקדש מורה מאד, גמר בלבו ליסד
>   תורה על מכוניה בבבל, ויבחר לו לשבתו את העיר נהר-פקוד הקרובה לנהרדעא.
>
> When oppression increased on our people, R' Chananya the son of the
>   brother of R' Yehoshua HaLevi went out to safety amongst our brothers
>   in Babylon and when he saw the great poverty in Eretz Yisroel, decided
>   to establish Torah in  Babylon and decided to settle in Nehar-Pekod,
>   near Nehardeya.

[This article about Babylon in the אנציקלופדיה אביב](http://school.kotar.cet.ac.il/KotarApp/Index/Page.aspx?nBookID=48202809&nTocEntryID=48338930&nPageID=48207308) 
mentions the main towns of  Babylon in which Jews settled amongst which is Nehar-Pekod.

There is an article in [Encyclopaedia Judaica](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/nehar-pekod) which reads:

> NEHAR PEKOD , according to earlier scholars a town in the district of
>   Nehardea (Babylonia), and according to more recent research, between
>   Sura and Nippur. Nehar Pekod gained note after the tanna R. Hananiah,
>   the nephew of the tanna R. Joshua b. Hananiah, settled there following
>   the suppression of the Bar Kokhba revolt in Ereẓ Israel (Sanh. 32b).

[This map](http://www.imninalu.net/maps.htm#Nebukhadnetzar) shows the town of Nippur.

So it seems that Nehar Pekod was a **town** in Babylon.